# Ember transitionTo query params does not update the URL

Tags: ember.js

I'm using Ember 1.9.1 and having an issue when transitioning to a route with query params.

The `queryParams` don't appear in the url.

I got **http://localhost:8080/login** instead of having http://localhost:8080/login?email=myemail&uuid=myuuid

```
App.MyRouteRoute = Ember.route.extend({ 

redirect: function (model, transition) {
    this.transitionTo('login', {
        queryParams: {
            uuid: model.get('uuid'),
            email: model.get('email')
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Could you setup demo on emberjs.jsbin.com or ember-twiddle.com?

Comment: Yes sure ! http://emberjs.jsbin.com/weciniriva/1/edit?html,css,js,output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify `queryParams` and `uuid`, `email` in `LoginController`:

```
App.LoginController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['uuid', 'email'],
  uuid: null,
  email: null
});
```

[Working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zacagazuwi/1/edit?html,css,js)

> http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zacagazuwi/1#/login?email=test%40gmail.com&uuid=myuuid

Comment: Thank you! This has helped me a ton!